# Shadow in graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want draw in plantuml MVC diagram, but shadow is not work as I want.

```
@startuml
digraph G {
node[shape=box, style=rounded, shadow_offset=7, shadow_blur=5];Model;View;Controller
    View -> Model
    Controller -> View
    Controller -> Model
}
@enduml
```

I want to draw
[image]

Comment: You have to explain *how* the shadow isn't what you want.

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that there are `shadow_offset` or `shadow_blur` attributes available for nodes?  I can find nothing like that in the Graphviz documentation.

Comment: I found it here http://msc-generator.sourceforge.net/help/5.4/Graph-Language-Tutorial.html , but here http://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html I cannot found anything connect with shadow,you are rigtht

Comment: The linked page suggest that msc-generate has additions, like shadows. Not sure if that project still lives...

Answer (score 1):

Using the `neato` layout engine with extra node for background, you can create something that looks like a shadow.
Image:
[image: shadow under node on the graph made with graphviz neato]
Script:

```
graph { 
    layout=neato
    node [pin=true shape=box style="filled, rounded" ]
    
    under [
        pos="0,-0.05"
        color=none
        fillcolor="black:white"
        style="radial, rounded"
        gradientangle=0
        width=.8]
    over [pos="0,0" fillcolor=white ]
}
```